# switch off broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android

I want to send an sms to someone's phone before the phone get switched off. here is the broadcast receiver but it does not work.

```
 public class SwitchOff extends BroadcastReceiver {
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
 public SwitchOff() {
    super();
  }

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    sendSMS(sharedPreferences.getString("number", "error"), "Child Name:" + 
 sharedPreferences.getString("childName", "Service child Name not found") +
            "\nStatus: Mobile is being turned off");
    Toast.makeText(context, "i am going to turned off",     
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
 private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null,
            null);
  }
}
```

and here is my manifest

```
<receiver
    android:name=".SwitchOff"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF"     
        />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: does this broadcast is being called ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.